# How to boot from usb in rpi3b+ when my scard is also inserted

Tags: pi-3

I have rpi3b+ a 32 gb scard and a sandisk usb 16 gb .
I want to boot only from my usb though I have my scard inserted 
  That's it..
Sorry if my language is pour

Thank u

Comment: I would think if your SD card does not have a bootcode.bin in the primary FAT partition, then the pi would attempt to boot from the USB instead - what's on the SD card?

Comment: An alternative is [Boot flow](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/bootflow.md) - however, there are caveats to using that ... I would recommend you read it, then read it again, then only if you're sure that is your only solution, you read it again, and then go through with it

Comment: If the SD card is bootable, the RPi prefers that to the USB drive.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear.

If you have a bootable SD Card the Pi will boot from that.

It is possible to have boot code on a SD Card and boot to a root partition on a USB drive. This is usable even on older models which do not support USB boot.

All that is needed is to change `/boot/cmdline.txt` so `root=PARTUUID=…` points to the root partition (which needs to have `/etc/fstab` set to mount this partition as root).

This can be used to use a read-only SD Card, and a read-write partition on a HDD or SSD.